# ON DUPLICATE KEY query - pulling out the primary key of a table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query which I would like to `INSERT` some data into my table however, if there is already data inside of a particular field `checkPoint`, then run an `UPDATE`. After a lot of research on here, users have suggested using ON DUPLICATE KEY.

This query works however as apposed to updating an already existing row, it inserts a new one, with a new primary key, please can someone explain where I have gone wrong, or what I've missed out.

```
<?php
      $idUsers = $_SESSION['id'];
      $ModuleID = 5;
      $checkPoint = 999;

      $query= "INSERT INTO `userTakingModule` (`userTakingModuleID`, `idUsers`, `ModuleID`, `checkPoint`) VALUES (NULL, $idUsers, $ModuleID, $checkPoint) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `idUsers` = VALUES ($idUsers), `ModuleID` = VALUES ($ModuleID), `checkPoint` = VALUES ($checkPoint) "; 

      $result = $conn -> query($query);
?>
```

Screenshot of my database layout: the table called `userTakingModule` in the middle is where the query is applied to.

[image: <code>checkPoint</code> Screenshot]

This is what is happening at the moment as I need to include the Primary Key of `userTakingModuleID` into the query somehow. (I almost need to say, look for where there is an already existing entry of the same `idUser` and `ModuleID`?)

[image: Table Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part of using `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is telling MySQL what the key is, so it can look for duplicates. You said:

> I almost need to say, look for where there is an already existing entry of the same `idUser` and `ModuleID`

And that's exactly right. You need to create a UNIQUE index on those two columns like so:

```
ALTER TABLE userTakingModule ADD UNIQUE INDEX(idUser, ModuleID);
```

Now, conflicts will trigger the update functionality. You should just remove the `userTakingModuleID` column from your query altogether, it will be given a value automatically as needed. You're also mis-using the `VALUES` function; you should pass it a column name, and it will resolve to the value that would have been inserted into that column without a conflict. So you can use *either* the `VALUES` function, or the variable itself.

And speaking of variables, I would be remiss if I didn't point out how insecure and dangerous it is to insert variables directly into queries. You should always use prepared statements. You don't provide enough code to know which database API you're using, but for PDO it would look like this:

```
  $idUsers = $_SESSION['id'];
  $ModuleID = 5;
  $checkPoint = 999;

  $query= "INSERT INTO userTakingModule (idUsers, ModuleID, checkPoint) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE idUsers = VALUES (idUsers), ModuleID = VALUES (ModuleID), checkPoint = VALUES (checkPoint)";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute([$idUsers, $ModuleID, $checkPoint]);
  $data = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And for mysqli something like this (though I'm not too familiar with it)

```
  $idUsers = $_SESSION['id'];
  $ModuleID = 5;
  $checkPoint = 999;

  $query= "INSERT INTO userTakingModule (idUsers, ModuleID, checkPoint) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE idUsers = VALUES (idUsers), ModuleID = VALUES (ModuleID), checkPoint = VALUES (checkPoint)";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bind_param("iii", $idUsers, $ModuleID, $checkPoint);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: Hi @miken32 thanks so much for your help, so should I just completely get rid of the primary key in `userTakingModule` table of `userTakingModuleID` and then create a new primary key of  `idUser, ModuleID`?

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS, I am using PDO so made it safer with your suggestion, can I just say thank you so much, I have been trying to work on this for such a long time, I was so close haha and you have solved it! Have a wonderful evening :)

Comment: Ha, just do this for 20 years and you'll be able to pull this stuff out of your hat at a moment's notice too.

Comment: Just a real quick one, in the mysqli version, which I'm using, how in the update query where it says `idUsers = VALUES (idUsers)` etc, does it know the value to put in, if it's not taken by the variables? (need a good nights sleep with this solved in my head lol). Does it just look to the variables passed on the INSERT side of the query?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html "In other words, `VALUES(col_name)` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause refers to the value of `col_name` that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred."

Comment: Peaceful nights sleep coming up :) x

Comment: Yes it just looks at the values in the `INSERT` section, and it's the same as re-inserting the values using PHP, but why add more `?` and bind more variables when you don't need to.